Realtime data transfer from Python to Java
What is the best way to solve the following problem:
I have a python script to subscribe to realtime incoming data. The data is pushed from the publisher (it is a blackbox but my guess is it creates a queue of rows which it pushes to me one at a time)
I would like to push the data immediately as I receive it to a java application
What is a way or an optimal way to implement this
My currently solution is to flip the pattern i.e.
The java server request the via rest every so often
So the python script caches the data received and java application request the data at frequent interval
The problem with this solution is that

the request is now made at intervals rather than realtime
instead of serializing just one row, it now serializes a who dataset which would take time
so total time to get the data into java is now taking time

What is the best way to handle this
My currently solution is to flip the pattern i.e.
The java server request the via a webclient every so often
So the python script caches the data received and java server request the data at frequent interval

Is it possible for Java web app to subscribe to the same real time data source as the python script does? If so, I would just get the data from the source instead of getting relayed from Python app.

Define what is real time. And what is the criteria for "best way to handle this". The question is too broad as it is. It is not possible to provide an answer that is an opinion, which is off topic for this site and the question could be closed.

@Ikigaiprogrammeh no it is not possible for the java web app to subscribe to the data source

@aled by realtime I mean I want to receive the data in the java application as soon it it published by the data source
so i want to reduce the latency between when the data source published the data, goes through python then to java as much as possible
My best way right now is to collect a batch of data in python then java application requests the data at regular (small) intervals
My concern with this solution is latency to serialize a list of data in java compared to serializing single data points

What is the actual latency? What is the maximum acceptable latency? How long are 'small' intervals? Where is the code?
